# shell script to pass element in a list over a sql query

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hive, scripting

I have a parameter $tbl which is having list of tables .for example (tbl1 tbl2 tbl3).
Now from my shell script i am running a hive query as below.

```
hive -e " select min(column_name) from db.tbl1 
          union all select min(column_name) from db.tbl2 
          union all select min(column_name) from db.tbl3 " > a.txt
```

Now the list may vary in the script ie if sometimes it's 3 tables then in the next iteration the variable may store 4 tables.. can anyone suggest how to parametrize the query so that it will pick up all the values in the list and pass it in hive query.

Comment: Loop on the elements in the list, and each loop builds the query.  Once the query is all done, then call `hive` with it.

Comment: @Nic3500 hi.. I am using below. for tbl in "${table[@]}" do echo "select min(column_name) from db.$tbl union all " > a.hql done .. the issue with this is the last tbl iteration is also printing union all. i dont want this last union all and want a semicolon in the end. can anyone help me with this.. I am a newbie in scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash

table=(tbl1 tbl2 tbl3)

# The select takes the 1st table
sql="select min(column_name) from ${table[0]}"

# Remove 1st table
unset table[0]

# Add union statements
for T in ${table[@]}
do
    sql+=$'\n'
    sql+="union all select min(column_name) from db.$T"
done

sql+=";"

echo "$sql"
```

The result is:

```
select min(column_name) from tbl1 
union all select min(column_name) from db.tbl2 
union all select min(column_name) from db.tbl3;
```

---

- the first table is used in the `select`.
- once used, it is removed from the array.
- then you loop on the remaining tables, for the `union` statements.
- and finaly add the `;` at the end.

You can adjust as required if your query changes.